# ReactJs rotate functionality not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, rotation, windows-7-x64

**Environment:**

- OS: Windows 7 - 64 bit

I am trying to rotate a div in **Reactjs** using click and drag mouse event as like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/ny6jqtLj/4/) one in **javascript code** which is working perfectly.

I did a [ReactJs app](http://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/o5L8g4ra/107/), with the reference of above given javascript rotate funtionality.

But in this ReactJs app, there is some problem to rotate with the handle, rotate not working properly as like javascript functionality.

**Javascript rotate code**

```
var dragging = false,target_wp,o_x, o_y, h_x, h_y, last_angle,origin_left,origin_top;
$('.handle').mousedown(function (e) {
  h_x = e.pageX;
  h_y = e.pageY; // clicked point
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  dragging = true;
  target_wp = $(e.target).closest('.draggable_wp');

  if(origin_left == undefined){
    origin_left = target_wp.offset().left;
    origin_top= target_wp.offset().top;
  }

  o_x = origin_left;
  o_y = origin_top; // origin point

  last_angle = last_angle || 0;
})

$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
  if(dragging) {
    var s_x = e.pageX, s_y = e.pageY; // start rotate point
    if(s_x !== o_x && s_y !== o_y) { //start rotate
      var s_rad = Math.atan2(s_y - o_y, s_x - o_x); // current to origin
      s_rad -= Math.atan2(h_y - o_y, h_x - o_x); // handle to origin
      s_rad += last_angle; // relative to the last one
      var degree = (s_rad * (360 / (2 * Math.PI)));
      target_wp.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
      target_wp.css('-moz-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
      target_wp.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
      target_wp.css('-webkit-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
      target_wp.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
      target_wp.css('-o-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
      target_wp.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
      target_wp.css('-ms-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
    }
  }
}) // end mousemove

  $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    dragging = false
    var s_x = e.pageX, s_y = e.pageY;

    // Saves the last angle for future iterations
    var s_rad = Math.atan2(s_y - o_y, s_x - o_x); // current to origin
    s_rad -= Math.atan2(h_y - o_y, h_x - o_x); // handle to origin
    s_rad += last_angle;
    last_angle = s_rad;
  })
```

How to make work **ReactJs app** as perfect as like **Javascript code**...?

Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: i am here to get help from tech peoples, don't discourage me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Greensock's Draggable tool: https://greensock.com/draggable it should simplify this quite a bit and it's free.

You can create a reference to the element you want to rotate and then use it on a lifecycle method of your component such as `componentDidMount` to create the draggable instance.

A bit like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
  Draggable.create(this.refs.dragTarget,{
    type:"rotation"
  });
}

render(){
  return(
    <div>
      <h2>React & GSAP Draggable</h2>

      <div className="draggable" ref="dragTarget">Drag and rotate me</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's a live sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/jRKBKXEqY

---

**EDIT 07-21-2017**

Create rotation feature without Greensock.

Here's a live sample without using Greensock:

https://codesandbox.io/s/XDjY28XoV

Consider this just a prove of concept, since it might need more work to use touch events and be fully crossbrowser.

Honestly I'd stick with GSAP since works excellent in all browsers and devices and the file overhead of TweenLite, CSSPlugin and Draggable is minimal.

Comment: I am searching for rotate functionality.. not draggable functionality.. And your live example not working..

Comment: Click on the blue square and move the mouse in circular motion while keeping the mouse button down, of course. The square is not going to move is going to rotate, that's why the `type` is set to rotation in the draggable constructor. The sample is working for me in chrome and firefox on windows 7 64

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo.. Good... I accept your answer.. But i need to know that there is any option to make work rotate a div using only React js without any other codes like Greensock..?